# Regex to pull out each non-space group

Tags: java, regex

**Input:**

```
2 43: 72: Y
```

**Desired Output:**

```
ArrayList<String> resultArr = { "2", "43:", "72:", "Y" };
```

My current code for creating this array is...

```
String stateString = "2 43: 72: Y";
String stateStringFinder = "\\s*(\\S+)(\\s*(\\S+))+";
Pattern stateStringPattern = Pattern.compile(stateStringFinder);

Matcher matcher = stateStringPattern.matcher(stateString);

while(matcher.find()) {
    resultArr.add(matcher.group());
}
```

The contents of resultArr however are `{ "2 43: 72: Y" }`, which shows that my regex is being too greedy, and matching the entire string.

How can I break it down so that it puts in each "substring" from the `stateString`, while ignoring the white space?

Comment: You know what your delimiters look like, so why not `split`?

Comment: Why is Perl in your tag list?

Comment: I figured the perlmonks would be able to help me lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String stateString = "2 43: 72: Y";
String[] resultArray = stateString.split("\\s");
List<String> resultList = Arrays.asList(resultArray);
```

You might want to consider `"\\s+"` as a delimiter, instead of simply `"\\s"`, to avoid having empty strings in your result when you have multiple consecutive spaces.

Comment: likely should be: String[] resultArray = stateString.split("\\s+"); to group together multiple spaces.

Comment: Ah yes :P that's what I want, forgot all about split.

Comment: You dont need to first in String[] and than List<String>. Only do following List<String> strList = stateString.split("\\s"); It consume less memory

Comment: @UmairSaleem: in what version of Java would that compile ?

Comment: Me too, and the exact snippet you wrote gives a compile error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to List<String>`

Comment: Works for me as long as I have import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.List;

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
String abc= "2 43: 72: Y";
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(abc.split("\\s"));
```

Answer (score 1):

What would be a lot easier is:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(stateString.split(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample code to address your query :

```
public class RegexTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "2 43: 72: Y";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        list.add(matcher.group());
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

}